# IndexedDB error in FireFox when calling createObjectStore

Tags: firefox, indexeddb

I'm trying to call createObjectStore on a newly credited indexedDB and getting this error in FireFox: InvalidStateError: A mutation operation was attempted on a database that did not allow mutations.

Here is my code:

```
var indexed_db = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB;

if (indexed_db) {
    var request = indexed_db.open("Map Tiles", 1);

    request.onerror = function(event) { };

    request.onsuccess = function(event) {
        var tile_store = event.target.result.createObjectStore("map", {keyPath: ["zoom_level", "tile_column", "tile_row"]});
    };

    request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) { };
}
```

The error is happening when I call createObjectStore.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like the createObjectStore can only be created in the onupgradeneeded function.  Once I moved my code there, it stopped throwing an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are basically three types of transactions with indexedDB: readonly, readwrite, and versionchange. You can add/remove objects to/from an object store in a transaction that is the readwrite type. Technically you can also add/remove objects in versionchange but it is not what I consider a best practice. However, you cannot create/remove object stores or indices in a readwrite/readonly type transaction (you get this error). You can only do objectstore/index create/remove in a versionchange transaction.

You can directly create transactions of the type readonly and readwrite, but you cannot create versionchange. versionchange only happens within an upgradeneeded event callback. Effectively you can only make changes in the onupgradeneeded callback. So, as your comment says, doing schema changes (add/remove stores/indices) outside of a versionchange transaction triggers this error, which is basically every transaction outside of the specially typed one provided inside onupgradeneeded.